# 301 redirect for wordpress permarlink

Tags: redirect

on `.httaccess`, we use like this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food/(.*)$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/$1
```

It works good. but we have a problem with 1 old link.
we used to have a multi-site and the name is "food". it changed to "food-for-healthy"

Therefore we have changed like these.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food/(.*)$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/$1
```

and as you know,

```
http//:domain.com/food/
```

and

```
http//:domain.com/food
```

are same.

The problem is `http//:domain.com/food` which needs to go to `http//:domain.com/food-for-healty/`

I have tried several things but it gets redirect error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /food http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy
```

this gets a redirect error. how can I change it to work properly?

Comment: I have put "http:" instead of "http://" I don't have enough reputation to put links. :)

Comment: while you happen to be using WordPress, this is an .htaccess question and would be more appropriate on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/
```

As per the syntax for [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), the URL part can not be a regex. So, to achieve that you may use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: it comes with a redirect error and goes to http://:domain.com/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/...

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. I updated my answer now. I hope that helps.